# How to make Jquery coded Dynamic Dropdown Menus work in harmony with PHP GET variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a Dynamic Dropdown Menus for 3 Game Types that is coded with jquery and php. For the Game Type Dropdown, if Baseball is selected the corresponding League will show only Baseball Leagues, if Soccer is selected the corresponding League will show only Soccer Leagues and so on.
This was achieved using jquery.
I am forced to use $("#game_type_id").change(); so that for whatever game type is selected, the corresponding league will be shown. But the disadvantage is whatever you choose on the League Dropdown after the page submit the selection never retains, because of the forced execution of $("#game_type_id").change(). But if we're going to check if the selection is correct, I can say yes, thru the php link, such as game_type_id=1&q_lid=64, it changes.

Is there a way to make this work in harmony with the PHP code?

HTML (Smarty PHP Framework)

```
Game Type:
<select id="game_type_id" name="game_type_id" style="width:100px;margin-bottom:5px;  margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 5px;">
 <option value="1" {if $game_type_id == 1}selected="selected" {/if}> Baseball</option>
 <option value="2" {if $game_type_id == 2}selected="selected" {/if}> Soccer </option>
 <option value="3" {if $game_type_id == 3}selected="selected" {/if}> Flexi </option>
</select>
League:
<select name="q_lid" id="q_lid">
 <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
  {foreach from=$league_list item=league}
  <option class="league_group league_group_{$league.game_type_id}" value="{$league.league_id}" {if $q_lid==$league.league_id} selected="selected" {/if}>{$league.league_short_name}</option>
  {/foreach}
</select>
<select id="fl_ctg" name="fl_ctg">
 <option value="0" > --Flex Category -- </option>
 {foreach $f_bet_type as $val}
 <option value="{$val.category_id}" {if $fl_ctg == $val.category_id}selected="selected"{/if}>{$val.category_full_name}</option>
 {/foreach}
</select>
<input type="submit" id="btn_search" name="btn_search" value="Search" style="cursor:pointer;width:50px;"/>
```

Js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(function () {
    $("#game_type_id").change();
 });

 var options = $("#q_lid").children(".league_group").clone();
 //Game Type Dropdown
 $("#game_type_id").bind("change",function() {
    var type = $(this).val();
    $("#q_lid").prop("disabled",false);

    if(type == 3)
        $("#fl_ctg").show();
    else
    {
        $("#fl_ctg").hide();
        $("#fl_ctg").val(0);
    }

    // select league according to game type
    $(".league_group").prop('selected', false)
        .remove();

    options.clone()
        .filter('.league_group_'+this.value)
        .appendTo('#q_lid')
        .first()
        .prop('selected', true);
    $("#q_lid").change();
});
//League Dropdown
$("#q_lid").bind("change",function() {
    var gtype = $("#game_type_id").val();

    if(gtype==3)
        $("#fl_ctg").show();
    else
    {
        $("#fl_ctg").hide();
        $("#fl_ctg").val(0);
    }
});

$('#btn_search').click(function()
{
    var q_lid = $('#q_lid').val();
    var fl_ctg = $('#fl_ctg').val();
    var q_str = '';

    if(q_lid.length > 0){
        q_str += '&q_lid='+q_lid;
    }

    if(fl_ctg.length > 0){
        q_str += '&fl_ctg='+fl_ctg;
    }

    if(game_type_id.length > 0){
        q_str += '&game_type_id='+game_type_id;
    }
});
```

PHP code

```
if( isset($_GET['q_lid']) && !empty($_GET['q_lid']) ){
  $q_lid = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['q_lid']));
}

if(isset($_GET['fl_ctg']) && $_GET['fl_ctg']<>0)
{
    $fl_ctg = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['fl_ctg']));
}
$smarty->assign('q_lid',$q_lid);
$smarty->assign('fl_ctg',$fl_ctg);
$sql_team_orderby = "league_priority DESC";
$league_data = LeagueClass::getLeagueDetails('', '', '',$sql_team_orderby, '');
$smarty->assign('league_list', $league_data);

$f_sql_category="SELECT * FROM category ";
$f_category_result=Db::getInstance()->queryExecuteFull($f_sql_category, $array = true);

$smarty->assign('f_bet_type', $f_category_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this dynamically with only PHP

```
<?php
    $game_type_id = $_GET['game_type_id']; // Game ID
    $league_list = array('league1', 'league2', 'league3'); // The list of all leagues
    $chosen_league = $_GET['league']; // whatever the league is
?>
```

Game type
    
        > Baseball
        > Soccer 
        > Flexi

League

```
<select name="q_lid" id="q_lid">
    <option <?php if ($chosen_league == '') echo 'selected' ?> value="" disabled>Select...</option>
    <?php
        // Output all the league list with the chosen one
        foreach($league_list as $option) {
            printf(
                "<option %s value='%s'>%s</option>\n",
                $chosen_league == $option ? 'selected' : '',
                $option,  $option
            );
        }
    ?>
</select>
```